# Can I preserved displayName when I wrote component inline function in React.memo()?

Tags: reactjs

I prefer  `const Foo = memo(() => <div>Hello World</div>)`  form when apply `React.remo()` to a Component, But this way lose display name in React Dev Tools.

So I always added `Loading.displayName = 'Loading'` this line to set displayName manually.
Can I create keep const variable name that asigned wraped `React.memo()` to somehow e.g. extend `React.memo` attribute?

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import { CircleLoader } from 'react-spinners'

const Loading: React.FC = memo(
  () => {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
        <CircleLoader size={250} color="#9CA3AF" />
      </div>
    )
  },
  () => true
)
Loading.displayName = 'Loading'

export default Loading
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use named function in `React.memo()`.

```
import { memo } from "react";

export default memo(function DisplayNamed() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello DisplayNamed</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[image: DisplayName with React.memo]

https://codesandbox.io/embed/displayname-with-react-memo-t1crw2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark